# Use of から in 家まで送るから

Tags: particle-から

I read somewhere that if から follows a verb, the use will be **because/reason**  is it always like that?

I got confused in this sentence:

> あぶないだろ家まで送るから

家まで送る is clear to me but I was thrown off because of から. Is the translation: *It is dangerous so (kara) I will take you (made) home* or should it be: *It is dangerous. I will take/see you until we reach your home*

Answer (score 0):

Another usage of から is *showing strong assertion or determination*. So if 家まで送る　translates into "I will take you home", then 家まで送るから can perhaps be "I will take you home (with a determined, won't-take-no-for-an-answer face)". By the way, any chance だろ　is actually だろう?

Comment: だろ is a casual, colloquial pronunciation of だろう.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it wrong to think of it as "so/because" ? から's phrase before it is the reason so it will not make sense if I say "because I will take you home" ? sorry do I make sense?

Comment: The two clauses in this sentence are “it’s dangerous” and “I’ll take you home”. To put in a causal relationship it’s either “because it’s dangerous, I’ll take you home”, or “it’s dangerous, so I’ll take you home”. In both cases, “I’ll take you home” is the effect of the cause-effect pair. から expresses cause (on top of origin of an action, and determination), which is attached to “I’ll take you home”. This contradicts the understanding of the relationship between the two clauses. On this ground, therefore, I guess it’s unlikely that から can been seen as “because”.

Answer (score 0):

I think there has to be some sentence after から.
危ないだろ　家まで送るから(歩いて帰らなくていいよ)
危ないだろ　家まで送るから(ちょっと待ってて)